# Why does x = 3 and x <<= 3 result in 24?

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning python programming language. I wonder that:

Why does

```
x = 3 and x <<= 3 result in 24
```

**?**

```
x * 3 * 3 = 27
```

Meanwhile:

`x = 27 --> x >>= 3` gives the same result as 3 and `x = 24` has the same result.

Thank you for reading.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLeul.png)

Comment: You should learn precysely what these operators do, without guessing.

Comment: Check out `bin(3)` and `bin(24)` as a starter

Comment: try to google Python `>>' bit shift.

Comment: `<<= 3` basically equal to `* 2 * 2 * 2`, so `3*8 == 24`

Answer (score 2):

```
X = 3 sets X to binary 11.

X <<= 3 shifts it left 3 bits to 11000 or 16 + 8 = 24.
```